# ddd: Should a domain class have injection on methods?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Here my current `Document` domain class:

```java
@Getter
@Builder
public class Document {
    private final DocumentId resourceId;
    private final ResourceLocation resourceLocation;

    private Document(DocumentId documentId, ResourceLocation resourceLocation) {
        validate(documentId, resourceLocation);
        this.resourceId = documentId;
        this.resourceLocation = resourceLocation;
    }

    public static Document load(DocumentId documentId, ResourceProvider resourceProvider) {
        if (resourceProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResourceProvider cannot be null");
        }
        ResourceLocation resourceLocation = resourceProvider.generateUploadResourceLocation();
        return new Document(documentId, resourceLocation);
    }

    public URI get(ResourceProvider resourceProvider) {
        if (resourceProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ResourceProvider cannot be null");
        }
        ResourceLocation downloadResourceLocation = resourceProvider.generateDownloadResourceLocation(resourceId);
        return URI.create(downloadResourceLocation.getValue());
    }

    private void validate(DocumentId documentId, ResourceLocation resourceLocation) {
        if (documentId == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid resourceId");
        }
        if (resourceLocation == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid resourceLocation");
        }
    }

}
```

My question is related with `load` method. As you can see, it has a `ResourceProvider` method parameter.

`ResourceProvider` has several implementations, that's why I need to "inject" it (I prefer to pass injection on method than as constructor parameter.

My question is:

1. Is it correct? Should domain classes have external service dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

No, domain classes as aggregator, entity, value object and domain service should not get service dependency on things like repository, service api, etc..

- (infra) controller ->

  - (app) use case ->

    - (domain) domain service, aggregate, value object, entity
    - (infra) repository, infra service as external service API

Domain must be isolated from external things, testing is harder, separation of concerns is violated, etc.

I recommend this book: Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software

Comment: What do think about [this article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/#:~:text=Domain%20model%20completeness%20%E2%80%94%20When%20all,out%2Dof%2Dprocess%20dependencies.). Why do you nest a second "infra" at the same level of "domain"?

Comment: e.g. CreateOrderUseCase.

You get user by userRepository (infra), and then you call domain service for checking price, or you create value object OrderId.

UseCase serves for the cooperation of these services or objects.

Look at this project: https://gitlab.com/food-delivery5161742/commerce